# Java truncating psexec output

Tags: java, output, outputstream, psexec

So here is the deal. I have a Powershell script that calls psexec to run a ping test from a remote system to it's connected network drive. This works fine and the ping output comeback and works great. But when I run the same script VIA runtime.exec or processbuilder in Java the only thing that shows up is part of the first line.

I have been reading all about this whole error stream and output stream stuff and tried about 3 dozen lines of code to try and fix this. Nothing has worked.

With that I have decided that maybe running the psexec code in a batch file and calling that from the ps1 script may work... lol nope

So now I am outputting the batch to a file and that is not working.

So my question is two different options.

1) does anyone have a workaround to this. As you know a ping command is around 11 lines and the one I want is the "Average = ms".

2) Is there a way to isolate the batch from Java when called from Java so that psexec output doesn't get truncated because Java doesn't know how to not cut off the output due to the error.

As requested, code that I am using.
*This pulls in the output from a powershell script*

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc;
proc = runtime.exec("powershell \\\\[computer]\\c$\\" + Main.setDirectoriesForScriptsAndLogs + "\\scripts\\TPCAuto.ps1 " +  pcname + " " + ticket + " " + usid + " " + Main.GUIver);
InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
Main.txtUpdates.setText("Gathering performance data");
AllUpdates.allUpdates.setText("Gathering performance data");    
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    //listens for key markers from the powershell script and displays the output to a JTestField or JTestPane
}
reader.close();
proc.getOutputStream().close();
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
return;
```

*This is the simplified powershell script*

```
[string]$Hostname = $args[0]
[string]$HdriveA = $args[1]
$GetDFSSplit= ""
$DFS = ""
$HomeDrivedropped = $HdriveA -replace ".{8}$"
$FindDFS = \\[computer]\c$\SDS\Extra\dfsutil.exe link $HomeDrivedropped
$GetDFSSplit = $FindDFS.Split("\") | select 
[String]$DFS = $GetDFSSplit[5]
write-host ". 2 @ DFS Host = $DFS"
$PingH = "ping $DFS"
$testingagain = \\[computer]\c$\SDS\Extra\psexec\psexec.exe -d \\$Hostname -s cmd /c ping $DFS > c:\temp\output.txt
write-host ". 5 @ $testingagain" <-- this is feeding to Java so it knows where to display the output
```

*Output when I feed the script manually and run it manually(not VIA Java) NOTE: that the powershell_ISE and Powershell consoles both show this as the result*

> Pinging server.being.pinged [IP.of.Server] with 32 bytes of data:
>   Reply from IP.of.Server: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=251
>   Reply from IP.of.Server: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=251
>   Reply from IP.of.Server: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=251
>   Reply from IP.of.Server: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=251
>
> Ping statistics for IP.of.Server:
>       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
>   Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

*output of script when run VIA Java with both manual and Java feed inputs*

> Pinging server.being.pinged [IP.of.Server]

This happens when I feed the results into Java or feed it to the txt file. I tired everything I could find from sysinternals site as well as others and the general consensus seems to be this is broke but I seriously doubt that.

Oh and let me add this in for fun I tried running a batch file with args to create the txt from powershell and still get the same return. I am at a total loss since everything else coming into my Java code prints just fine to the JTextField and Pane and there are some with longer outputs.

Also note that I even paused my Java code and powershell scripts thinking that the psexec wasn't able to finish before it was ended. Not sure I did it right though. And the 2>null keeps Java from crashing, which is a known issue.

Comment: "and tried about 3 dozen lines of code" - could you please show your best attempt? :-)

Comment: Java doesn't truncate data. Your code might, probably does.

Comment: I expanded the crap out of this. Please see all the added info.

Comment: Figured it out myself. Working 100% now!

Answer (score 0):

There is no true fix for the screwed up way that PSexec sends it output and PAexec simply failed to do anything. So now I am creating a batch file on the remote systems C drive and using psexec to tell the remote system to execute it. The ping command runs echo off and outputs to a file in the same dir. I then use powershell to parse the output file and grab what I want then delete the files.